# embedded video moves after refress

Tags: html, video, embed, embedding

I am building a new wordpress website for my church using the customify theme. When I put my embed code in, the video goes right where it is supposed to but then I publish and hit refresh and it moves really far down the page. What am I doing wrong. Embedding should be easy and I've never had an issue before. Nothing else moves down when placed there so it must be in the embedding code, right?

Comment: <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/111053882?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Try to take out the style attribute on your div. The positioning and padding could be due to this.

Change from

```
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
```

To:

```
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this for embedding videos, I send you an example with a random youtube video (you can change the height and width):

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="190" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eWZ2adCaKo4" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly when I put it in with the video you had but when I changed the video part (within the ") it went down where it was before. Why would changing only the video url do this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally put this in and it looks like it will work:

< iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/111053882" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

Thank you for your help!